# Define function with parameter whose type has an embedded type in Go

Tags: types, go

Very new to Go and so probably going about this the wrong way.

Let's say I have a type:

```
type Message struct {
    MessageID string
    typeID    string
}
```

And I create another type with Message embedded:

```
type TextMessage struct {
    Message
    Text       string
}
```

And then I want to create a function that will take any type, so long as it has Message embedded:

```
func sendMessage(???===>msg Message<===???) error
```

How do I do that?  My goal is to define the function such that it requires a type with a typeID member/field.  It would be ok (but less desirable) if it took an interface, in which case I assume I'd just define the interface and then define the appropriate method.  But unless that's the only way to accomplish this - what's the recommended approach?

Comment: Interface - definitely. Your other option is to accept an interface and type assert it in the function .. but thats icky-pants when there's a more type-safe way.

Comment: ...by "accept an interface" above.. I meant `interface{}`.

Comment: Ok, that's not so bad after I try it out.  Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing some obvious modality.  Make it an answer so I can accept?

Comment: @4of4: You don't need to change every single instance of `Golang` to `go`.  It's not important, and both are acceptable names (as seen in the tag wiki excerpt).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go the interface route:

```
type TypeIdentifier interface {
    TypeId() string
}

func sendMessage(t TypeIdentifier) {
    id := t.TypeId()
    // etc..
}
```

Your only other option is to type assert an `interface{}` within the function.. which will quickly become an out-of-control bowl of bolognese.

Comment: At first, the function seemed like overkill.  But once I got past that it flows nicely and allows the typeID to stay out sight, like I'd prefer.

Comment: More and more I find myself defining interfaces for this purpose and the code - although more of it - becomes much more finely tuned and clean. Everything just has small specific purposes and it flows nicely.